# Generating random numbers in a generic class

Tags: java, casting, numbers

I want to generate random id numbers in a generic class.
The user is supposed to be able to choose from most of the Number implementations.
Is my approach safe in the case of casting from Long to Byte?
I do not know what happens on a downcast like that. What number will it result in?
Will it find evenly distributed numbers?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
public class Test<I extends Number>
    {
       SecureRandom random  = new SecureRandom();
       I id = (I) random.nextLong();
       while(Test.has(id))
       {
          id = (I) random.nextLong();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to get cast exceptions here. What if `I` was some custom class you made? By all means thought, you should try it for yourself.

Comment: may i ask what is the purpose of this class ?

Comment: Agree w/r/t purpose.... A random number generator that creates Number instances, instead of primitives, will be much slower.

Comment: This is to be included in a much larger generic class that is supposed to return unused random ids to the user no matter what Class has been chosen for I.

Answer (score 1):

The Java `Number` class is not really designed for this kind of generic class use. You cannot cast like you are trying to do; there's no way (particularly after [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)) that Java could know what you are trying to accomplish. There's no auto-boxing, for instance, if `I` is `AtomicInteger`, `BigDecimal`, etc. (not that casting is the way to invoke auto-boxing in the first place).

I suggest that you redesign your application so it does not rely on such a beast as your proposed class. It's just not going to work.

Comment: The cast works as long as the random long is within the expected value range, like byte etc.
But if I would just have it cycle for a valid cast, I fear for a very costly id search when casting Long to Byte.

Comment: @JamieFlowers - You can use a `HashSet` to store your keys. The look-up cost will be essentially the same (and rather low) whether you are storing `Byte` or `Long` keys.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is just getting unique IDs, try the approaches given in the link, (Way-2 is similar to your approach)

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56